# Retrieve SSL/TLS connection information in MVC controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, ssl

I am trying to figure out how clients connect to my MVC web site. I can see the `IsSecureConnection` property in the `Request` object on the MVC controller instance.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var isSecure = Request.IsSecureConnection;
}
```

Is there a way to determine the details of the TLS/SSL connection that is used to retrieve information from my MVC web site? Escpecially I am interested in the applied TLS/SSL version and cipher suite.

Comment: Thank you both. Exactly what I was looking for but somehow couldn't find. Closed question as duplicate.